# Is there a context manager for temporarily changing matplotlib settings?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In `pandas` and `seaborn`, it is possible to temporarily change the display/plotting options by using the `with` keyword, which applies the specified setting only to the indented code, while leaving the global settings untouched:

```
print(pd.get_option("display.max_rows"))

with pd.option_context("display.max_rows",10):
    print(pd.get_option("display.max_rows"))

print(pd.get_option("display.max_rows"))
```

Out:

```
60
10
60
```

When I similarly try `with mpl.rcdefaults():` or `with mpl.rc('lines', linewidth=2, color='r'):`, I receive `AttributeError: __exit__`.

Is there a way to temporarily change the rcParams in matplotlib, so that they only apply to a selected subset of the code, or do I have to keep switching back and forth manually?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, using stylesheets.

See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

e.g.:

```
# The default parameters in Matplotlib
with plt.style.context('classic'):
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Similar to ggplot from R
with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You can easily define your own stylesheets and use

```
with plt.style.context('/path/to/stylesheet'):
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

For single options, there is also `plt.rc_context`

```
with plt.rc_context({'lines.linewidth': 5}):
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the `matplotlib.rc_context` function will do what you want:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with mpl.rc_context({"lines.linewidth": 2, "lines.color": "r"}):
    plt.plot([0, 1])
```